# AZ Devops Yaml Release?

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-self-hosted-agent, az

I don't know if is already released az devops extension to create pipeline release with AZ CLI. 
There are post relating to 1y ago. 
I found documentation here but I can't understant how to create various stage of release pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/release?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-release-create

Someone has already created release pipeline with yaml and tell me how please? Or just post some command to import into Azure-DevOps project?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , right now there is no way to automate the creation of classic release definition. You will need to create the definition and then you can queue a Release run using `az pipelines release create` command.

The role of `az pipelines release create` command is to kick off a new release for an existing release pipeline, not to create a new release pipeline.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/866) on github about this.

So as a workaround , it is possible to automate the new yaml pipeline definitions with  [az pipelines create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-create) command which can constitute both build (CI) and [release](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/unified-pipelines/) (CD).

First you can create a yaml file(e.g. azure-pipelines.yml) in the repo and set the definition for both CI and CD pipelines in the yaml file.  [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) can give you guidance.

Then you can create an Azure Pipeline for a repository with the pipeline yaml already checked in into the repository via `az pipeline create` command. Specify `--yaml-path` in the command.

> --yaml-path --yml-path :
>
> Path of the pipelines yaml file in the repo (if yaml is already
>   present in the repo).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I'm already using yaml path in the repo for automate creation of CI and CD Build Pipelines. For release I export from another project the JSON file and import in the new one, but then I need to set up all the variable for the new project and authorize task to my subscription just want to automate also this task

Comment: Service connections are only available at project level. If you want to authorize tasks to subscribe in another project, I think this cannot be achieved automatically.

Comment: @Cyber.Drunk  Not get your response for several days, service connections are created at project scope. A service connection created in one project is not visible in another project. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) about this. If this answer is helpful to you,would you please accept it as an answer?Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.